# cospectral graphs have isomorphic adjacency matrices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two cospectral graphs, then can we say that their adjacency matrices are isomorphic?

Comment: They are similar by orthogonal transformation, what do you mean by isomorphism?

Comment: If by isomorphic adjacency, you mean these two graphs must be isomorphic, your answer is no. But you must give clear definition of "isomorphic adjacency matrices".

Comment: Relevant: yasser could get a suggestion from [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226503/database-of-adjacency-matrices-on-cospectral-non-isomorphic-graph-pairs).